# About Tic-Toc-Toe Game in C language

Tags: c

I wrote a full code for this game using **do and while in C language** .. but I stop in point which I don't know how I can type a code to decide if the game is drawn or not..

Thanks

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char matrix[3][3]; 
char check(void);
void init_matrix(void);
void get_player1_move(void);
void get_player2_move(void);
void disp_matrix(void);

int main(void)
{
  char done,choise;

  printf("Welcome to the tic-tac-toe game!!!\n\n");
  printf("Rule for playing the game is:\n\n");
  printf("Each player must put the value of raw and column like: 1 2 to put his symbol in\nthe tic-tac-toe board.\n\n");
  printf("The tic-tac-toe board looks like as follows:\n\n");
  init_matrix();
      disp_matrix();
    printf("Are you ready to start the game?   ");
    scanf(" %c",&choise);
    if (choise == 'y'){

  do {

    get_player1_move();
    done = check(); /* if winner or not */
    if(done!= ' ') break; /* winner!*/
    disp_matrix();
    get_player2_move(); 
    disp_matrix();
    done = check(); /* if winner or not */
    if(done!= ' ') break; /* winner!*/

  } while(done== ' ');

     if(done=='X') printf("Player 1 won the game!!!!!\n");
     else printf("Player 2 won the game!!!!!\n");
    }

    else {
    printf("\n\nThank you!!!\n\n");
    printf("We hope you will play the game anther time....");
    }
  return 0;
}

/****************************************************/
void init_matrix(void)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    for(j=0; j<3; j++) matrix[i][j] =  ' ';
}

/****************************************************/
void get_player1_move(void)
{
  int x, y;

  printf("Enter row and column input for player 1: ");
  scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);

  x--; y--;

  if(matrix[x][y]!= ' '){
    printf("You can not choose this row and clumn!! Try again\n");
    get_player1_move();
  }
  else matrix[x][y] = '1';
}

/****************************************************/
void get_player2_move(void)
{
  int x, y;

  printf("Enter row and column input for player 2:  ");
  scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);

  x--; y--;

  if(matrix[x][y]!= ' '){
    printf("You can not choose this row and clumn!! Try again\n");
    get_player2_move();
  }
  else matrix[x][y] = '2';
}

/****************************************************/
void disp_matrix(void)
{
  int t;

  for(t=0; t<3; t++) {
    printf("                         :    :  ");
    printf("\n                       %c :  %c : %c",matrix[t][0],matrix[t][1], matrix [t][2]);
    if(t!=2) printf("\n                     ----:----:----\n");
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}

/****************************************************/

char check(void)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check rows */
    if(matrix[i][0]==matrix[i][1] && matrix[i][0]==matrix[i][2])
     return matrix[i][0];

  for(i=0; i<3; i++)  /* check columns */
    if(matrix[0][i]==matrix[1][i] && matrix[0][i]==matrix[2][i])
     return matrix[0][i];

  /* test diagonals */
  if(matrix[0][0]==matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][1]==matrix[2][2])
     return matrix[0][0];

  if(matrix[0][2]==matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][1]==matrix[2][0])
     return matrix[0][2];

  return ' ';
}
```

Comment: Can't help if you don't post code.

Comment: "but I stop in point which I don't know how I can type a code to decide if the game is drawn or not.." `#define MyGameLooksBoss #ifdef MyGameLooksBoss draw(); #endif`.

Comment: Do you really think this question can be seriously taken?

Comment: Have you written the code to test if either player has won? I presume you test that every time a move is made, and end the game if a line of three is formed. If there wasn't a line of three formed, and the board is full: that is a draw.

Comment: Please show us the code you have written than only we can help you out.

Comment: i wrote my code

Comment: Deciding a draw is not the only problem. When a player wins, the winning move is not shown, and it always says player 2 has won (even if it was player 1).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

`if(done=='X')` should be `if(done == '1')` because `matrix` contains `1` and `2`, not `X` and `O`.

To tell if the game is a draw, keep a count of the number of moves, and break out of the loop when it reaches 9. You only have to check this after player 1 moves, because player 2 always moves on even numbers.

There's no need to use `do{...} while (done == ' ')` because the code always breaks out of the loop when `done != ' '`. So just use `while(1)` to make an infinite loop.

```
int count = 0;
while (1) {
    get_player1_move();
    done = check(); /* if winner or not */
    disp_matrix();
    if(done!= ' ' || ++count == 9) break; /* winner or draw */
    get_player2_move(); 
    disp_matrix();
    done = check(); /* if winner or not */
    if(done!= ' ') break; /* winner!*/
    ++count;

}
if (done == ' ') {
    printf("It's a draw!\n");
} else {
    printf("Player %c won the game!!\n", done);
}
```

Comment: @Chemist exercise 2: predict a draw before the board is full ;)

Comment: You'll have to do that in the `check()` function. If every row, column, and diagonal has two different player numbers, no one can in. You can return `d` in that case, and change to `if(done == ' ' || done == 'd')`

Comment: Thanks Mr.Barmar ,, can i convert my code  using ( if statments for and while ) insted of function and how ?? thank you @Barmar

Comment: If you want to use the same code in multiple places, it's best to use functions. The code for `check` is best kept in a function.

Comment: Oh Thanks, But it's possible to conver it ? @Barmar

Comment: Anything is possible, it just makes the program more complicated.

Comment: @Chemist Why did you try to edit my answer into just a bunch of "CLOSED"?

Answer (score 0):

Set a boolean variable "draw" as false and if no player wins and all 9 moves are done and no free block is available set the "draw" as true. And calculate the result based on "draw" that either the game is a draw or not.